# Is there a difference between calculating in template vs calling a function?

Tags: angular

Does Angular make any effective distinction between the two approaches? Is there any situation where one approach would be "better" than another?

Does it matter if there are a hundred elements and only a few will have have value of `foo` change upon a change?

Approach A

```
<div>
 foo(item)
</div>

foo(item): number {
  return (item.x * item.y) + this.variable
}
```

Approach B

```
<div>
 {{ (item.x * item.y) + variable }}
</div>
```

Comment: no difference in angular. the difference is just how you structure your logic

Comment: Depending on the situation, you should NOT be using Approach A. Reason being that it can be called multiple times.

Comment: @StackoverBlows are you saying in certain situations that A would be called, but not B? What situation would that be?

Comment: @TruthOf42 Example: you have a list of 100 items, Approach A would be called 100 times.

Comment: @StackoverBlows and why wouldn't approach B also be evaluated a 100 times as well?